# How to set the width of Material UI drawer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use material UI drawer by anchoring it to `top`, its working ok, but only thing is i am not able to change the width of the drawer, its taking full width of the page. I tried to update the width in css like

```
 list: {
    width: 250.   //tried to update it to 100, but its not taking
  },
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-iib83?file=/demo.js:599-627)
How to update width?

Comment: what exactly u want to change?
the width of the whole drawer the comes from the top or the inner list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the `Drawer` `paper` you've to change.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    width: 250
  }
});

<Drawer
  anchor={anchor}
  open={state[anchor]}
  onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
  classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
>
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Answer (score 10):

For MUI version 5, you have to use the `PaperProps` prop like so:

```js
<Drawer
  PaperProps={{
    sx: { width: "90%" },
  }}
>
  /* ...child elements */
</Drawer>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have figured this out using the docs? I know the [API page](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/drawer/) for `Drawer` mentions `PaperProps` but it's not obvious that that's how the width is set. Or would you have had to go through the source code?

Comment: There's no clear way in the documentation. 
However, if you have worked enough with mui, you would notice that the base element in the Drawer is a `<Paper />`. 
This is how one might conclude that setting the width on the `<Paper />` element might affect the width of the `<Drawer />`.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styling also can be written as follows when required.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  
});

<Drawer
  anchor={anchor}
  open={state[anchor]}
  onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
  style={{ width : "100px"}}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Drawer takes the width of the inner most element.

```
const useStyle = makeStyles({
 list: {
    width: 150
  }
});

<Drawer>
   <Container className={classes.list} /> 
</Drawer>
```